# Call React setState() function from async callback function

Tags: reactjs

How we can call react set state from Sync callback function for example

```
MyClass.getAynchFunction(inputParam, function (err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
     }
}
```

I want to set variable from 'data' object in react component state.

Comment: Where is `MyClass.getAynchFunction` executed?

Comment: thats a seperate class

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a guess because you're not specifying what exactly doesn't work, but I'm guessing you're getting something like `this.setState is not a function`.

That's because `this` isn't the React component inside your callback function. There's basically two ways to fix this

```
// Bind the current this to the callback function.
MyClass.getAyncFunction(
  "input",
  function(err, data) {
    this.setState({ responseData: data });
  }.bind(this)
);

// Rewrite it as an arrow function so the current this is automatically bound.
MyClass.getAyncFunction("inputParams", (err, data) => {
  this.setState({ responseData: data });
});
```

I would go with the arrow function because it's cleaner.