# Return text from selected shape in Powerpoint with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I am currently building a task-pane add in for powerpoint and I am struggling with extracting the text of a shape with the Javascript API and assigning it to my `this.state.editor`. The code snippets I found online all look something like this - which does not work (although I have not found an exact example for text):

```
  getData = () => {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        this.setState({ editor: asyncResult.error.message});
      } else {
        this.setState({ editor: asyncResult.value });
      }
    });
  };
```

The following function however works for INSERTING text

```
  insertText = () => {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(this.state.editor, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        showNotification("Error", asyncResult.error.message);
      }
    });
  };
```

Unfortunately I am not finding a hint in the documentation what exactly is being returned by the `getSelectedDataAsync`. Does anyone here have an idea?

EDIT: to be specific with "doesn't work" I meant, that my state (that is used to fill a text area) is not updating. The following snippet works in script lab:

```
function getSlideMetadata() {
  Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
      console.error(asyncResult.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4));
    }
  });
}
```

So I would assume,that the returned value is actually, what I want.
My current issue with that is, when I try to write the results like this:

```
  getSlideMetadata = () => {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.error(asyncResult.error.message);
      } else {
        this.setState({ selectedText: JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4) });
      }
    });
  };
```

to my state:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(title, isOfficeInitialized) {
    super(title, isOfficeInitialized);

    this.state = {
      selectedPage: 0,
      editor: "",
      history: [],
      loading: false,
      inputFocused: false,
      selectedText: "begin",

      // setting
      modelOptions: [],
      responseLength: 400,
      temp: 0.5,
      model: null,
    };
    this.editorRef = React.createRef();
    this.title = title;
  }
```

The state doesn't seem to update (as I can't see the text area that shows the content of `this.state.editor` update. When I replace the state with a self written string like "test" it updates...

Comment: Please provide more information than "does not work". What goes wrong? What do you expect to see and what do you actually see? Also, can you create a [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hey I edited the question. The problem seems evolve around writing the result of getSlideMetadata to this.state.editor

Comment: Well, `this.setState({ selectedText: JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4) });` is going to update `state.selectedText`, if it updates anything. So, it is expected that it wouldn't update `state.editor`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, what do you see if you have these 3 lines in the "else" block? `console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4)); this.setState({ editor: JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4) }); console.log(this.state.editor);`

Comment: unfortunately this code is within a task-pane add-in for powerpoint. console.log doesn't work there... I would love to see that too.

Comment: Can you run it in Script Lab like your first snippet?

Comment: I tried to but it seems like script lab doesn't support react..

Comment: I will try running it on my windows PC, I think there are some Microsoft developer tools available to potentially read out the console

Comment: Solved it: See below. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

So in the end this worked. Not sure why. Maybe I had to bind `this`to the function. Not having error messages while developing kinda sucks.

```
  getSlideMetadata = async () => {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, {}, (asyncResult) => {
      if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error.message, null, 4));
      } else {
        this.setState({ editor: JSON.stringify(asyncResult.value, null, 4) });
      }
    });
  };
```

This thread brought me onto it:
[Call React setState() function from async callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786954/call-react-setstate-function-from-async-callback-function)

Comment: It looks like the only functional difference between this version of getSlideMetadata and the one in your original question is that you are now using the correct state property `editor` instead of `selectedText`, which I mentioned in my second comment to your question. The comment that ends "Am I missing something?" Your problem was just a typo.

Comment: the version in my initial question  doesn't work with "editor" neither, ```selectedText```was something I used for debugging, but I tried both. I guess since it's not an arrow function, it doesn't know what ```this``` is.